# Смена цвета в прогрессе

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть прогресс бар, в котором указывается выполненный процент. Например,

```css
.progress {
  width: 220px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #E1E7ED;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-line {
  width: 50%;
  background:#5FB053;
  height: 23px;
  position: absolute;
}
.progress-percent {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2.2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-line"></div>
  <div class="progress-percent">Выполнено 50%</div>
</div>
```

Как изменить цвет текста `Выполнено ..%` на белый только в той части, которая заполнена зеленым цветом?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно поместить внутрь `.progress-line` ещё один div с "Выполнено ".

```css
.progress {
  width: 220px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #E1E7ED;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-line {
  width: 50%;
  background:#5FB053;
  height: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.done-progress-persent{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 220px; /*должен быть такойже как и .progress*/
  padding: 2.2px;
  color: #fff;
}
.progress-percent {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2.2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-percent">Выполнено 50%</div>
   <div class="progress-line">
     <div class="done-progress-persent">Выполнено 50%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

При увеличении прогресс бара некоторые буквы будут "разрезаться" на белую и черную часть (можно увидеть при 48%).